# MongoDB Mongoose storing same date and time

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Uploads `Schema` where I have stored the uploaded file's date like:

```
uploaded_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now(),
    }
```

By saving date as such, mongoose stores the date and time of files exactly the same. eg:

```
uploaded_date: 2020-05-19T08:10:00.034+00:00
```

when I upload multiple files  within a minute or so. Why is this occuring? Should I use `timestamp` for differenciating times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **Date.now** instead of Date.now()

Mongoose will replace Date.now with the current datetime when creating a new record, so it will update for every record. But, if you would use Date.now() your default value will be set to a fixed time(the creation time of your schema).

```
uploaded_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
}
```